# How to evaluate the accuracy of of coefficients $a,b,c$ in evaluating $z$?

Tags: estimation

The following formula is the SCS equation for evaluating Cumulative Infiltration :

$$z=at^b+c$$
In the equation $c=0.6985$ is a constant but I am allowed to use $c=0.7$ as an estimation. I have a table for the values of $z$ and $t$ ( it denotes the cumulative infiltration for the any specific time $t$ and I evaluated $z-c$ too)  :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
t& z&z-c \\ \hline
 5&1.7&1  \\ \hline
 10&  2.7&2\\ \hline
 15&   3.6&2.9\\ \hline
 25&  5.1 &4.4\\ \hline
 45&   6.2&5.5\\ \hline
 60&   7.7&7\\ \hline
 75&   9.2&8.5\\ \hline
 90&   10.7&10\\ \hline
 110&   12.7&12\\ \hline
 130&   14.7&14\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Then we have $z-c=at^b$ and I substitute $z-c=z'$ and then by taking logarithm we have:

$$\ln(z')=\ln(a)+b\ln(t)$$

Then in order to find the value of coefficients $a$ and $b$ I choose two points $t_1=10 , z'_1=2$ and $t_2=15 , z'_2=2.9$ and evaluated their logarithms and after substituting in the above equation I got system of equations and found $\ln(a)$ and $b$ and finally $a$ and $b$.

But in the second part of the question I am asked to evaluate the accuracy of these three coefficients for the estimation of $z$. I have no idea how to do it. Am I supposed to taking differentiate or something like that?

Comment: Notice that you get different values for $a$ and $b$ for every pair of points that you decide to choose! So you have to use the whole data set to estimate $a$ and $b$. Presumably you are supposed to use some kind of least-squares estimation. But it sounds like you don't know what that is?

Comment: @TonyK our professor told us it is more precise to use regression in Excel rather than this method (for homework). but I am preparing for the exam and I think I'm supposed to use this method.

Comment: "I'm supposed to use this method": what method? You haven't mentioned any methods. (Unless you mean the "method" of choosing two points at random, which isn't really a method at all.)

Comment: @TonyK Yes I meant choosing two points. And I think you are right I should say it is better to evaluate the coefficients with least square method "Excel exponential interpolation" which gives the coefficients right away.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "power" rather than Exponential.